# Grid View column is not enabling in editable mode

Tags: vb.net, gridview, webforms

> I am binding the data table in the grid view on the aspx page after the displaying data grid I want to edit some data but it is not in editable mode.

> I have tried this

```
Public Class COMP_SELECTION
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load, MyGridView.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim ddt As DataTable
            ddt = Session("compSelectionGrid")

            MyGridView.DataSource = ddt

                MyGridView.DataBind()

        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```